# Is 16x20 feet big enough for a 2 car garage?

Tags: garage, barn

I have an existing structure that is currently a single car that i'd like to convert to a two car garage; it measures 16x20 feet. The two garage doors would be mounted on the longest side (20 feet).

Would 16 feet be sufficient to back into and be ok? Has anyone ever seen or attempted a 16x20 two car garage?

Comment: [Google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?num=40&safe=off&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS590US590&hl=en-US&ei=TGTAWYrFA-GXjwTgk7y4DA&q=dimensions+2+car+garage&oq=dimensions+2+&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.0l5.1727.3630.0.4774.3.3.0.0.0.0.104.286.2j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.3.286...0i67k1.0.x6p7bO2Zjk8) 20x20 is a better minimum, I did see at least one 16x20 result.  I think you'll need a single double width door tho, you can't fit 2 singles.

Comment: You are really asking if cars are significantly shorter than 16 feet.  The answer is "only some are".  Generally you're pretty safe with trendy urban green "Whole Foods parking lot" sort of cars.  Gunrack, Elmer Fudd with 6-guns, Cracker barrel parking lot sort of cars, don't get your hopes up.

Comment: 2 sub compacts would fit fine but neither of my crew cab trucks would fit

Answer (score 1):

The ideal size will vary with the size of the vehicles you drive. There is a vast difference in the space required to comfortably open the doors and exit a Mini Cooper and a full size pick-up. I live in an older home with a 2 car garage built in the 1920's. The inside dimensions are 18' by 18'. To fit 2 cars (06 and 08 Chevrolet Impala) in it, the one on the left must be backed in and the one on the right driven in. Exiting the vehicle requires caution to keep the doors from dinging each other. Opening the passenger doors is impossible as there is less than a foot of clearance to the wall. Doing any kind of repair or maintenance in the garage is impossible with both cars inside.